# Use Google Form to pull value from table when the data entry is only a partial match

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown, google-forms

I have a google sheet that contains Property ID and Owner Name. I want users in a Google Form to enter part of a name in a Short Answer question, and have the next question in the Form be a dropdown with all the Owner Names that match that partial name entry. Then I want user to select the correct name and have the third question be a dropdown with all the Property IDs that match that Owner name.

Data validation in Forms doesn't work, I think I can do it with app script but I'm not sure how. I've searched for similar approaches like student names and IDs, but can't find one.

Comment: There is no programmatic interaction possible with Google Forms until they are submitted.

Comment: You could do this with an html dialog or webapp.

Comment: Thanx, sounds like I need to approach this differently. Users might have to search the Name/ID table, then copy and paste the ID into the Form. Not elegant, but it should work.

Comment: You're only giving us parts of the scenario. e.g. ` I want users in a Google Form to enter part of a name in a Short Answer question` - what is the Name that they are searching? How many Name/ID rows of data are on the spreadsheet?

Comment: What if you uploaded the Name/ID table to Google Forms? I think there is a limit of 1,000 rows in a Dropdown, but if the list is sorted, then when one starts typing, the form goes straight to names beginning with those typed letters.

Comment: Thanx, Tedinoz. I have 550 properties. I'll work on that today.

Comment: Thanx, all. Life issues pulled me off this project for a while. Tedinoz solution to load the Name/ID table works well on a PC, but my users don't like it much on a phone. I have another issue, same application, but I'll put that in a new question. Thanx again.